# Within the where condition we filter using row, Is there any way to index on it?

Tags: postgresql

So within a postgres select statement, I have this query which filters like this as an example.

```
select *
from table1
where ROW (table1.created_on, table1.id) < ROW ('2022-02-05 09:37:06.719', 'b8e4c048-ec10-4c7e-9811');
```

Can we index this?

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo to the example. I have adjusted it to table1

Answer (score 0):

Just a plain multicolumn index should do it

```
create index on table1 (created_on, id)
```